# ckeditor wysiwyg does not return textarea value in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm using a ck editor in my form but it do not return the data on submitting form .i'm getting all data of other form elements except the value from ckeditor.
And i tested that field by removing the ck-editor class (as an ordinary text area) then i'm getting the value.But i need to add a ck-editor other than ordinary text area in my form.
I'm working on laravel4.

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <textarea  class="form-control txtEditor" name="auctionDescription" id="auctionDescription" > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit............</textarea>
</div>
```

for testing i'm printing the values in my controller using

```
print_r(Input::all());
```

then i get result as

```
Array ( [_token] => tVThwNaVckCvWJChChbPleZaVdvNzAONwSjREkaA [campaignId] => 1 [auctionTitle] => Auction item 1 edited [auctionDescription] => )
```

ie:value of title and id entered using text box is returning but text in ck-editor is not returning.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?  ckeditor should be returning the data just as a normal textarea would using the name attribute of the text area it's been attached to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value from CK Editor instance and set it:

`$( "#auctionDescription" ).val(CKEDITOR.instances.auctionDescription.getData());`